# Sony Xperia Z4 stuck at boot after upgrading to Android 6.0

Tags: boot, 6.0-marshmallow, sony-xperia-z

A few minutes ago, my sony xperia z4 tablet noticed me to upgrade to android 6.0.
Now my tablet no longer boots. There is just a text "Error" and a little lying android man.

I tried to Reboot in Recovery Mode by Holding Power and Volume Up Key but it does not work. Nothing happens.

What can i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Download [Sony PC Companion](http://support.sonymobile.com/global-en/tools/pc-companion/) for Windows/Mac.
2. Shutdown your tablet and connect it to PC in recovery mode while holding down volume up/down key. Instructions will be shown on-screen if you're not clear with my explanation.
3. Click on **Repair my phone/tablet**.
4. Follow on-screen instructions afterwards. It'll take sometime to download necessary files.
5. If everything goes right you should disconnect the device and boot it up. Remember first boot takes more or less than 5 minutes.
6. Support link just in case if needed --- [Repair using PC Companion [detailed]](https://talk.sonymobile.com/t5/Xperia-Ion/Detailed-Software-Repair-Instructions-using-Pc-Companion-Win-or/td-p/249946).

Comment: That what worked for me last time I updated Sny